# How can I know if a function has been called or not?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a small reusable module for my use. and stopped on a point in my code which is, how can I make sure that the consumer of my module has called a function I provided to him or not in one of the methods of my module?

Basically, the API of the module looks like the forEach method, where my module passes internally arguments just like how forEach works

```
myModule.myMethod(callbackFunc, z)
```

`myModule` internally calls your `callbackFunc` with the following arguments:  `anotherFunc`, `x`, `y`

## Example usage:

```
myModule.myMethod((anotherFunc, x, y) => {
    if (x == true) anotherFunc()
}, z)
```

How can I know that the consumer of the `myMethod` has called `passed_function` or not?

Comment: I'm sorry if the variable names are unclear, I'm the worst when it comes to naming variables

Comment: Set a boolean named `fnCalled` default to false, then set it to true when called.

Comment: @code, cool, I think it's  the only solution (thinking in 2022, just for the history to record my thoughts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `anotherFunc` is something you create internally, you can write it so that it updates a boolean, and then later you can check that boolean. For example:

```
function myMethod(callback, z) {
  let hasBeenCalled = false;
  const anotherFunc = () => {
    hasBeenCalled = true;
    // ...
  }

  callback(anotherFunc, 'hello', 'world');

  if (hasBeenCalled) {
    console.log('they called it!');
  }
}
```